# How can pyqtgraph expands downward in a big size image?

Tags: image, size, rows, expand, pyqtgraph

I try pyqtgraph for some days. Here is an example, it saves a np.ndarray as an image simply, even no showing them, but the image can't **expands downward** by add rows. It always paints these rows in a fix area, which height of 480 by default. The rows are more, the height are less for each of rows, untill to collapse. The size maybe a little big, wide*1500. But cols show are right, the rows will be faults.

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters

mtx = np.random.normal(size=(12,18))
    
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=False)

win.resize(800,1500)  # much more heigth than common picture

pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True, foreground=(255,255,255))
print(win.size())

rows, cols = mtx.shape
for row in range(rows):
    win.addPlot(title='row: '+str(row), y=mtx[row])#, size=(300,100))
    win.nextRow()
    # if more rows will be collapsed
    if row > 5:
        break

ex = pyqtgraph.exporters.ImageExporter(win.sceneObj)
ex.export(fileName="array_noshow_scene_2x5.png")
```

Environment: Ubuntu-18.04, anaconda3-python3.7
3-rows:
[3-rows are clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEAem.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXsYJ.png)
5-rows:
[5-rows are fuzzy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXsYJ.png)

Comment: if it coding win.show(), or pg.xxxx.(show=True), the multi rows in image are all in right way; but it have to abort python UI by man-hand then, only if it gives a close() function by couple